# ¿Es correcto usar el plural en "las europas"?

Tags: plurales

Por motivos varios estuve escuchando a varias personas decir "las europas" como por ejemplo

> ¿Sabías que Anastasia fue a **las europas**?

No encontré una fuente fiable que responda esto, así que dejó aquí la pregunta.

Sé que en algún punto de la historia las personas se refirieron a India como **las Indias**, pero realmente ¿es correcto usar el plural? ¿Existe alguna clase de regla para esto que me estoy saltando?

Comment: «Las Europas» siempre podría ser correcto y normal de las misma forma que cuando hablamos de, por ejemplo, una división general entre la sociedad europea (la europa pobre y la europa rica, por ejemplo, o la capitalista y la socialista) o entre varios momentos históricos.  Pero en singular, ha constancia de usos que parecen ser no contrastivos desde el siglo decimonónico.

Comment: En el pasado era dicho sólo en contextos coloquiales, y por personas de bajo nivel cultural. Me suena al siglo XIX, principios del XX. Si alguien lo utilizara en la actualidad, lo asociaría al mismo tipo de contexto.

Comment: @Gustavson Yo lo vengo escuchando (uso irónico o estilístico o como se llame) hace un tiempo en Argentina. Y más todavía: *las Uropas*.

Comment: He oído un uso similar cuando algunos dicen "Vamos a las Niágaras". Quizá porque es más largo decir "... a las cataratas del Niágara", o quizá suena muy seco decirles sólo Niágara: "Vamos a Niágara" o "Vamos al Niágara". Estos últimos dos son correctos, pero unas personas lo hallan menos expresivo quizá. En el caso de las Europas, será una referencia a que son varias naciones, todas de Europa, que dan la idea de plural. Así que si no voy sólo a Francia, sino en un viaje a varios países de Europa, eso da la idea de que voy a las Europas... En todo caso, yo creo que es un uso coloquial.

Comment: @walen Sólo "las Europas", en oraciones como: *(X persona) se nos va para las Europas.* El contexto habitual era que alguien abandonaba su lugar (generalmente de clase no adinerada) para irse a un destino prohibitivo para el resto.

Comment: Las Uropas (Europa) refiere a un término de español antiguo. Se usaba en el siglo XIX. Ahora sólo se usa en tono humorístico.

Comment: Gracias por le comenatior @Migue, ¿tienes alguna referencia de eso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La RAE [acepta el uso de artículo antes del nombre de países y continentes](http://www.rae.es/consultas/india-o-la-india-de-peru-o-del-peru), si bien solo para casos donde se ha usado así históricamente:

> Muchos nombres de países pueden usarse opcionalmente precedidos de artículo: *(el) Canadá, (los) Estados Unidos, (la) India, (el) Líbano, (el) Perú*, etc., siendo diferente en cada caso la preferencia mayoritaria por una u otra opción. (...) Para saber qué nombres de países admiten el uso opcional con artículo, puede consultarse el [Apéndice 5: Lista de países y capitales](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/paises-y-capitales-con-sus-gentilicios).

El [punto 5 de la entrada del DPD sobre el artículo "el"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=8Tu5qHMtQD63wEn6zW) amplía información al respecto:

> **5. Uso con topónimos.** (...) Muchos nombres de países, y el de algunos continentes, pueden emplearse con o sin artículo, como es el caso de *(el) Afganistán, (el) África, (la) Argentina, (el) Asia, (el) Brasil, (el) Camerún, (el) Canadá, (el) Chad, (la) China, (el) Congo, (el) Ecuador, (los) Estados Unidos, (la) India, (el) Líbano, (el) Pakistán, (el) Paraguay, (el) Perú, (el) Senegal, (el) Uruguay, (el) Yemen,* etc. La preferencia mayoritaria por el uso con o sin artículo varía en cada caso, aunque con carácter general puede afirmarse que la tendencia actual es a omitir el artículo. Por otra parte, los nombres de comarcas, ríos, montes, mares y océanos van obligatoriamente introducidos por el artículo: *la Amazonia, la Mancha, el Orinoco, el Ebro, los Alpes, el Himalaya, el Mediterráneo, el Pacífico,* etc.

Hablando específicamente del continente americano (no europeo), el DPD [dice que](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=hBnnxR9MOD6YmtLAqN):

> **América**.
>   2. No existe razón alguna para censurar el plural *las Américas*, que tiene larga tradición en español y resulta una denominación expresiva válida, alusiva a las distintas áreas o subcontinentes (América del Norte, Centroamérica y América del Sur): *«La iglesia de San Pedro Claver, el primer santo de las Américas»* (GaMárquez Vivir [Col. 2002]). Este plural expresivo está también presente en la locución *hacer las Américas*, usada en España con el sentido de ‘hacer fortuna en América’.

Según todo lo anterior, el uso de "las Europas" para referirse al continente europeo o a los países de Europa **no sería correcto**, puesto que históricamente no se ha empleado así. Podría serlo si se estuviese hablando de por ejemplo las diferencias entre las zonas de Europa (países del este vs. países occidentales, etc.)<sup><sub>1</sub></sup>, pero no es el caso del ejemplo dado en la pregunta.

Mi sensación personal es que su uso pretende simplemente imitar la expresión *las Américas*, bien en tono jocoso o bien sarcástico.

<sub>1. Ejemplo de este uso [en este enlace](https://books.google.cl/books?id=iUCuqDzBKsoC&lpg=PA1&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q=las%20europas&f=false) proporcionado por [Rafael](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21516/es-correcto-usar-el-plural-en-las-europas/21828#comment42940_21828).</sub>

Comment: A falta de contexto, se me ocurre que en América se podría usar esta expresión como reflejo del *las Américas* que mencionas. Es decir: igual que los emigrantes españoles iban a *hacer las Américas*, hoy día se podría decir que los emigrantes americanos se van a *hacer las Europas*.

Comment: De acuerdo, coloquialmente su uso es de sátira o ironía, en sentido jocoso mayormente. En mi país no es usado por gran parte de la población, se escucha sobre todo en grupos/familias con mayor educación que el promedio de la población (tomar en cuenta que tal promedio es bastante bajo).

Comment: Ya que tu respuesta fue aceptada, sólo quería sugerir que agregaras una referencia académica al contexto en que sí se puede hablar [en plural de las Europas](https://books.google.cl/books?id=iUCuqDzBKsoC&lpg=PA1&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q=las%20europas&f=false).